# Alias class is not available in OpenXML Sdk

Tags: vsto, openxml-sdk

I am trying out OpenXML and downloaded sample code from here 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2010/02/26/open-xml-sdk-office-services-better-together.aspx

The code is not building for me. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [SdtAlias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.sdtalias.aspx)